# Ansible variable override default in another role

Tags: ansible

I'm unsure how to override variables between roles in Ansible.

To simplify the setup a little, I have two roles applied to the same host. The first role defines a variable in its `default/main.yml`:

```
do_some_task: yes
```

And looks for that variable in its tasks:

```
- name: Some Task
  when: do_some_task
```

The second role overrides that in its `vars/main.yml`, which is supposed to take precedence over the defaults:

```
do_some_task: no
```

However, the task is still being run, indicating that the variable wasn't overridden. It seems that the override is scoped to the tasks of the second role. I tested that by adding a debug task to both roles:

```
- name: Test some task
  debug: "msg='do_some_task = {{ do_some_task }}'"
```

This confirms that the first role sees a different value of the variable than the second.

```
TASK: [role1 | Test some task]
ok: [myhost] => {
    "msg": "do_some_task = True" 
}

...

TASK: [role2 | Test some task]
ok: [myhost] => {
    "msg": "do_some_task = False" 
}
```

The common answer to this appears to be to set the variables in the inventory or the host vars. However this isn't particularly DRY: if you have many hosts in different inventories, you'd have to set the same variables in lots of places.

So is there some way of overriding a variable from another role?

Comment: I never tested this but always thought vars and especially defaults are only available for the role they are defined in. What should work though is to use the `set_fact` module.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this post from Michael DeHann](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ansible-project/eI3jTyUaJTU/5tlIj6ZK894J) about variable location, role defaults, etc.

Comment: There are two downsides to `set_fact`. First, it only applies _after_ that task has been run, so if role1 runs before role2 then it doesn't apply. Second, if you use tags to tell Ansible to only apply the tasks from the first role and not the second, it won't run that task. The same is true of the `include_vars` task.

Comment: Why don't you define the variable for second role also in defaults? Also by role you don't mean two tasks right ?

Answer (score 3):

If you use Ansible >= 2.2, you maybe able to use `include_roles`:

```
  - name: Pass variables to role
    include_role:
    name: role1
    vars:
       do_some_task: "{{ role2_do_some_task }}"
```

You can also use dependencies of roles for Anslbie >= 1.3. Write the `role2/meta/main.yml` like:

```
  ---
  dependencies:
  - { role: role1, do_some_task: yes }
```

If you want neither, given that you don't want to put the variable definition in playbook, the only sensible place to define them is in inventory.

You can define the ones that need to overwrite the role1 default in the same group:

```
  [overwrite_do_some_task]
  host1
  host3

  [overwrite_do_some_task:vars]
  do_some_task=yes
```

If you don't give the variable value before running role1, then the expected behavior is, use the role default, which is what OP observed.

Note: It is more readable to prefix role variables. i.e. use `role1_do_some_task` instead of `do_some_task`. Doing so, you are less likely to confuse yourself. See [Ansible Best Practices: The Essentials](https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-best-practices-essentials).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wrap a role with another role then you can override the inner role's variable by specifically passing variables from the outer role.

So as per your example you would have an inner role task of:

```
- name: Some Task
  when: do_some_task
```

This inner role would have a variable set like this:

```
do_some_task: true
```

And then you can override the inner role when you are calling your outer role in a playbook like this:

```
- name: outer-role
  hosts: outer-role-nodes
  roles:
    -   role: outer-role
    - { role: inner role,
        do_some_task: "{{ do_some_task }}" }
```

This should take the `do_some_task` variable from the outer role and override the inner role's `do_some_task`.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid putting the variables in the playbook. The question is boiled down to a single variable because that's easier, but in practice it could easily be a large number of variables. I don't want to repeat those in several playbooks, or several inventories. I want to set a single flag - assigning a host to a role - and have that bring in all the necessary config. Nice and DRY.

Comment: @MarcusDowning did you find anything satisfactory?

Comment: Not really. Afaict, Ansible doesn't like anything leaking from one role to another.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR : to be able to inherit defaults/ config, you have to separate it into other roles and include it where it's going to be used**

One way to apparently work around this is to create a separate role which will hold the defaults, and then import/include it in your main role. The roles you create with the default configurations can import each other as a way of "inheriting" configuration from defaults, and then the main role would load the top-most configuration role and take all the configs as expected..

For example, in my case I want to have a templating system which has a "stacked" level of configuration.. all of them inheriting from a base set of config in defaults, and not vars, otherwise you can't override it from inventory.

these are the roles:

- template-base
- template-config-standard
- template-config-performance

-> Template-base has the whole logic for deploying templates based on the selected configuration.. this has some logic to include the selected config role on the tasks files

-> template-config-standard has the standard set of config defined in defaults/main.yml, and nothing else

-> template-config-performance has some additional tweaking on the defaults/main.yml file, but does not repeat anything from template-config-standard, and instead simply uses it on "import_role" on the tasks/main.yml file.. probably dependencies still work

In a bit more examplified way:

role template-base:

```
- files/ (contains all the template files)
- tasks/
|---- main.yml (contains the code below)

# Includes the template configuration based on the selected template
- include_role:
    name: "template-config-{{ selected_template}}"
    public: true # Important so that configs are exposed here

- ** Does templating work **
```

role template-config-std:

```
- defaults/
|---- main.yml (contains a bunch of configuration)
```

role template-config-perf:

```
- defaults/
|---- main.yml (contains just a few config items, overriding stuff from the role above)
- tasks/
|---- main.yml (contains below code)

#Simply includes the standard configuration.. all this does is take defaults in the defaults/main.yml file from the below role
- import_role:
    name: template-config-std
```

The approach above seems to work just fine, respecting the desired inheritage of variables and precedence. It looks like you cannot have the role that will use the variables competing with the roles that contain the default variables, unfortunately, because it will always win.. but in any case the example above seems okay :).. if you need to add more things other than just configuration to the supporting roles, you have to create a kind of mechanism on the main role, but hopefully nothing very complex..

Good luck and have a good one!

PS: one of the most important aspects of this approach is that we keep the default/ precedence on the configuration, meaning the inventory can override it if needed!